# Regexp assertions - either both or none

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match any number that is not preceded by **x** and also not followed by **y**.
I came up with something like this:
`(?<!x)(\d+)(?!y)`

However, that doesn't really help as I also want to match the numbers in strings like `x123` or `456y`.

In other words, I want either both assertions to work or none.

Examples:

- From "x123", "123" would be matched
- From "456y", "456" would be matched
- From "789", "789" would be matched
- Nothing would be matched from "x123y"

Can you help please?

Comment: Are the numbers part of a larger string? Also which language?

Comment: @FailedDev Yes they are. The language is PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<!\d)(?!(?<=x)\d+(?=y))\d+
```

Basically, you create a regex for what you **don't** want to match - `(?<=x)\d+(?=y)` - and put it in a negative lookahead.  If that succeeds, you can go ahead and consume the digits.  But that's not enough, because it will still match `23` in `x123y`.  Adding a negative lookbehind for a digit ensures that the match only starts at the beginning of the run of digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it as a single PCRE expression, but just plain code where you have the possibility of extra control structures, you can do it like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach $_ (qw(x123 456y x789y)) {
    while ($_ =~ /\d+/g) {
            print "$_\n" if !!(substr($`, -1, 1) ne "x") ^
                            !!(substr($', 0, 1) ne "y");
    }
}
```

And here is the PCRE (single-expr):

```
foreach $_ (qw(x123 456y x789y)) {
    print "$_\n" if
            /\D*\d+(?!\d)(?!\D)|(?<!x)(?<!\d)\d+\D*/;
}
```

Explanation:
Alternation 1: it is allowed to have a non-digit (\D), then a bunch of digits must follow \d+, and if so, there must be no digit trailing (serves so that it does not end up matching just "x78" out of "x789"), and also no non-digit.
Alternation 2 is the exact reverse, i.e. there must be no x and no digit before the first matched digit, and after \d+, there may be anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!x\d+y)x?(\d+)y?
```

Basically, you assert that the overall match will only succeed if you **don't** have an `x` followed by `\d+`, followed by an `y`. Then, you proceed to match the number (you need to include the optional `x` and `y` in order to match `x123` and `123y`, but you know from the assertion, that you will never match both `x` and `y`).

Here's a simple [test](http://ideone.com/ytu3k) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
(\b\d+|\d+\b)
```

**Test** in `perl`:

Content of *script.pl*:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    printf qq[$1\n] if m/(\b\d+|\d+\b)/;
}   

__DATA__
x123
456y
789
x123y
```

Running the program:

```
perl script.pl
```

Result:

```
123
456
789
```